# external JSON file to HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, html, json

I need to take a external JSON file containing an array of values and use those values in an HTML/Javascript file to create a 2D canvas. I am not sure how to access the external file and parse it. Any suggestions? A sample of what the JSON file looks like is below.

```
{   
"rectangles" : [
    {
    "x_coor":"0", 
    "y_coor":"0", 
    "width":"20", 
    "height":"10"
    }
]}
```

Comment: That's besides the point

Comment: well it won't be if that's what your actual json looks like.

Comment: Okay, I'm super new at this and that is what a bunch of online resources made a JSON array look like. Feel free to include a short example of what an array should look like. i would really appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to load JSON files is with AJAX:

No library: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/xhr-responsetype-json

or if you want JQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/